# MS Access/SQL query with duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some help figuring out how to structure a query in MS Access to be used to create a monthly report of profile/role changes of the employees. Table `tbl_mov` is made by comparing staff on month[n] vs staff on month[n-1] and so figuring out hirings or resignations and whom changed his role.

Table `tbl_mov` is:

```
id | DATE | MOV | NAME | PROFILE
 4 | Feb  |  +  | Mark |   tech 
 2 | Feb  |  +  | Joe  |   legal
 3 | Feb  |  -  | Mark |   ict
 1 | Jan  |  +  | Carl |   legal
```

I am trying to obtain something like this:

(February vs January)

```
MOV | NAME | PROFILE | cngROLE | mov1.id | mov2.id
 +  | Mark |  tech   |  true   |    4    |    3
 -  | Mark |  ict    |  true   |    3    |    4
 -  | Joe  |  legal  |  false  |    2    |    2
```

What I get instead are duplicate rows:

```
MOV | NAME | PROFILE | cngROLE | mov1.id | mov2.id
 +  | Mark |  tech   |   true  |    4    |    3
 -  | Mark |  ict    |   true  |    3    |    4
 +  | Mark |  tech   |   false |    4    |    4
 -  | Mark |  ict    |   false |    3    |    3
 -  |  Joe |  legal  |   false |    2    |    2
```

I structure the query as:

```
SELECT [...], *IIF* AS cngROLE 
FROM tbl_mov AS mov1 
INNER JOIN tbl_mov AS mov2 ON (mov1.date = mov2.date AND mov1.name = mov2.name)
```

With the `IIF` statement to be:

```
IIF((mov1.mov <> mov2.mov AND mov1.profile <> mov2.profile); TRUE; FALSE)
```

I understand why I get more rows than expected but I don't know how to fix it.

Let me know if I have to add more details. Thanks everyone

EDIT: added `id` (pk) column

Comment: Formatting problems

Comment: you need a column that is unique so you can add mov1.id < mov2.id else if they are real duplicates you can add DISTINCT

Comment: @nbk can you clarify why mov1.id < mov2.id should work? tbl_mov has a unique column (PK) but applying your solution doesn't work, I get only one row.

Comment: add a auto_increment so that the rows can be detemied, the numbers give an order so that youu will not get any duplicates

Comment: @nbk thx. Do you mean to add the auto_increment column id on `tbl_mov`? Because there already is, I updated the post.

Comment: yes add the column to the `ON`

Answer (score 1):

The profile change for Mark did not occur across months, it occurred in same month. There is no record for Mark in Jan so can't really look at month(n) and month(n-1) to compare - can only compare sequential records for each Name, regardless of when they occurred.

Can retrieve previous profile with a TOP N correlated subquery.

```
SELECT Id, [Date], [Name], Profile, 
(SELECT TOP 1 Profile FROM tbl_mov AS Dupe 
   WHERE Dupe.Name=tbl_mov.Name AND Dupe.ID<tbl_mov.ID
   ORDER BY Dupe.Id DESC) AS PreProf,
IIf(Profile <> PreProf, TRUE, FALSE) AS cngROLE 
FROM tbl_mov;
```

| Id | Date | Name | Profile | PreProf | cngROLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | Carl | legal |  | 0 |
| 2 | Feb | Joe | legal |  | 0 |
| 3 | Feb | Mark | ict |  | 0 |
| 4 | Feb | Mark | tech | ict | -1 |

Be aware slow performance of correlated subqueries on large dataset is a known issue. If your data were in SQLServer, there are intrinsic functions available to handle this requirement.

Possibly just as useful and certainly faster performing would be a simple report listing profile assignments grouped by Name.

Comment: Thx for your help. Your solution seems to be working but running the query takes so much time that it's not usable